# Rails collection of current + past 30 days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, collections

So I've got a collection called @events and I am defining it as

```
@organization.owned_events.current.reverse
```

However, what I would actually like to do is have not actually current, but anything current or expired in the last 30 days. I tried

```
@organization.owned_events.current-30.days.reverse
```

But this just provided an empty collection. I think this is because what I actually want is not current-30.days, but actually current AND current-30.days

Not sure how to write that though. Can I somehow define another term instead of current like net_thirty and make that equal current or within last 30 days?

Answer (score 1):

In your event model you can do:

```
scope :from, ->(duration){ where('your_datetime_field_here > ?', Time.zone.now - duration ) }
```

Since you want to filter by a date or datetime field, previous option is for a datetime field, if you want to filter by a date field:

```
scope :from, ->(duration){ where('your_date_field_here > ?', Time.zone.today - duration ) }
```

`->(){}` is a block you are passing to the scope.

You would use these scopes like this:

```
any_events.from(30.days)
```

In your case:

```
@organization.owned_events.from(30.days)
```

You could also want to filter events not after today:

```
scope :from, ->(duration){ where('your_date_field_here BETWEEN ? AND ? ', Time.zone.today - duration, Time.zone.today ) }
```